# How do you run all the Jest LWC tests at once in VSCode?

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code, lwc-jest

The "Run Test" link is provided for each test as illustrated below. But what is the easiest way to run all of the tests in the file?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in this [Test Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/lwc/testing/) documentation:

> To run all test cases in a Jest test file, click the play icon on the
>   menu bar in the top right corner of the editor window.

i.e. the green arrow:

[image]